# Python pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use pandas DataFrame in PyCharm. When I try typing DataFrame - as per the screenshot below - DataFrame doesn't show up. When I manually type it, it show up like that. Finally, when I try to run the script it brings up this error: *AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'*. (the script file is just for demonstration). Pandas installed version is 2.0.2, PyCharm version 2023.1.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: What it the output of `print(pd.__version__)` or `print(type(pd))`?

Comment: What is the output of `print(pd)`? You probably accidentally created a module named `pandas` that's shadowing the actual pandas module.

Comment: Please always post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](/q/36250353/4518341)

Comment: @Corralien `print(type(pd))` is always going to be `<class 'module'>`. Maybe you meant `print(pd)`?

Comment: @wjandrea. Yes if `pd` is a module. I didn't want to see the full path of the module but you are right if the module is "shadowed" it's important to see the path of the module! Good point.

Comment: I did run print(pd) and here is the output:
<module 'pandas' from 'C:\\*\\*\\*\\venv\\pandas\\__init__.py'>
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @Corralien What would it be besides a module?

Comment: A variable. Like `pd = ...` but the screenshot shows it can't be that.